# A method to calculate the total ammount of kills a specific player got

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a table of information on it, showing who died during a game.

I was wondering if there is a way to detect how many players each person killed and display that on the FFA output section of my spreadsheet?

[EXCEL File on Google Drive :)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQonKwIfRRcOjo3gUd5uRyI-P08Bm15aYmpSIYdvyoON394naVxg9bF9pkmG7x1eQi6z1msG5qrERyg/pub?output=xlsx)

Comment: please post the data as text.  Many will not trust downloading files from unknown sources.

Comment: There is a way. How much flexibility do you have over the contents of Sheet1? The additional info in the "Killed By" column is problematic (e.g., ` - Lvl 1 ('(@@)')`. If you can add a helper column, this is easy using COUNTIF function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do it in one formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2 & " - ",Sheet1!$G$5:$G$26))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The additional info in the "Killed By" column is problematic (e.g., `- Lvl 1 ('(@@)')`.

**If you can add a helper column, this is easy using COUNTIF function.**

In column H, Sheet1, add this formula and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(G5,FIND("-",G5)-1)),"")
```

[image]

Then, on your FFA Output sheet, use this formula, drag down:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!H:H,'FFA Output'!E2)
```

[image]

**If you can't use a helper column, then you probably need a VBA solution.**

A VBA solution would just loop the column and essentially extract the Player Name from the Killed By column and keep a tally of each. This would basically translate the functions used in the formula solution (above) to VBA code.